# Creating new instance of object without using "new"

Tags: c#

I faced with the code below

```
XmlReader xmlreader = 
    XmlReader.Create("http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
```

here to make a new object of `XmlReader`, it just used calling method of `XmlReader`.

I know here `Create` is a static method, but it is a little odd for me.
I used to exploit `new` word to command making new instance.

Can anyone please tell me how does this line works?

Comment: [Just look at the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,009e2d1038282c97). (Follow it down to [the actual `new` call](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderSettings.cs,450)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method you're calling does it for you:

```
public class XmlReader {
    public static XmlReader Create(String url) {
        // There's probably a lot of fancy code in this method, but it'll use new somewhere
        return new XmlReader(...);
    }
}
```

(It's possible to avoid `new` altogether by using a technique called *reflection*, but that's not what's going on here.)

Answer (score 10):

This is an example of a factory method.  (Which can often be a step toward using a separate factory object.)

Somewhere in `XmlReader.Create` it is internally making use of the `new` keyword.  In order to instantiate a new instance of an object, you need to use `new` to call a constructor.  To reduce coupling between objects, however, you may abstract that behind a factory method or factory object.

For example, these two implementations do roughly the same thing:

```
public class Widget
{
    public Widget() { }
}

//... elsewhere ...

var widget = new Widget();
```

And:

```
public class Widget
{
    private Widget() { }

    public static Widget Create()
    {
        return new Widget();
    }
}

//... elsewhere ...

var widget = Widget.Create();
```

In an example this simple, there's little difference between the two.  As code evolves and becomes more complex, there can be a number of compelling reasons to choose one over the other.  For example:

1. There are complex constructors and you want to expose a simple interface for building an instance.
2. The constructors are likely to change often and you want consumers of your library to have a single unchanging interface.
3. There is significant logic invoked when building an object and you want to move that logic to its own object.
4. You want to use a separate object for mockability in automated testing.
5. You have a more complex inheritance structure and want to expose a top-level abstract factory.
6. etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's a static method that, in it's body, creates a new object (using `new`) and returns it.

You can emulate the pattern like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static Foo Create()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo
{
 public string Prop { get;set; }
 public Foo(string prop)
 {
  Prop = prop;
 }

 public static Foo Create(string prop)
 {
  return new Foo(prop);
 } 
}
```

This is how it can look like under.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons to create factory Methods. Do you want control about all the Instances created of a Type? For example you could do something like that:

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyClass() // private constructor optional
    {}

    public void Create()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }

}
```

(private constructors are often used to implement the [Singleton Pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx))

Factory Methods could also be in a seperate Class.

```
public class MyClass {
    internal MyClass() // means only Classes of same assembly may access this
    {}

}

public class MyClassFactory {

    public void NewMyClass()
    {
        // Do some license checking here or whatever
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

> Factory Methods define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses.

Read more about [Factory Methods here.](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern)